# How to Replace with()

Tags: javascript, with-statement

I've been reading up on with() and trying to figure out how to rewrite this piece of code.

```js
    _$createRootItemAreas: function() {
        var areaSize = 50;
        var sides = { y2: 0, x2: 0, y1: 'y2', x1: 'x2' };
        for( side in sides ) {
            var area = this.root._$getArea();
            area.side = side;
            if( sides [ side ] )
                area[ side ] = area[ sides [ side ] ] - areaSize;
            else
                area[ side ] = areaSize;
            with( area )
                surface = ( x2 - x1 ) * ( y2 - y1 );
            this._itemAreas.push( area );
        }
    },
```

Should it be:

```
area.surface = ( x2 - x1 ) * ( y2 - y1 );
```

or

```
area.surface = ( area.x2 - area.x1 ) * ( area.y2 - area.y1 );
```

Comment: You have two suggestions of what might work, why not just try both?

Comment: `with` applies to *all* variables in the block, whether they are read or written, they are attempted to be accessed as properties on the object. However, it really depends on what the `area` object is (what properties it has).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
area.surface = ( area.x2 - area.x1 ) * ( area.y2 - area.y1 );
```

is the solution. I found another version of the same code where somebody had already fixed the issue and thus provided the solution.

Thank you to @Bergi for the explaintion.